# SVG Border Issue using WkhtmltoPDF

Tags: svg, border, wkhtmltopdf, pdfbox

I'm using `WKHTMLTOPDF` for generating `PDF` everything looks fine except that when `WKHTMLtoPDF` is rendering `SVG` (a chart) it is generating border around it and i want to get rid of it.

Here is url of page, i want to convert:

http://cvldev.isni.co/Print.aspx?p=eyJBc3NldExpc3QiOiI3MiIsIlJlcG9ydENvZGUiOiJBQ0FOIiwiRGF0ZUZyb20iOiIxOC8xMS8yMDE1IDAwOjAwIiwiRGF0ZVRvIjoiMTgvMTEvMjAxNSAyMzo1OSIsIkxhc3RSZXBvcnRlZCI6IjI0IiwiU2hvd0FsbCI6ZmFsc2UsIlNwZWVkVHJlc2hvbGQiOjAsIlJlcG9ydFR5cGUiOiIiLCJGdWVsUHJpY2VQZXJMaXRlciI6MSwiQ2hhcnRUeXBlIjoiQ29sdW1uM0QifQ==

This is css i am using

```
tr { page-break-inside: avoid;}
svg { border: none; }
```

and these are parameters

```
 --javascript-delay 60000  --user-style-sheet E:\freelarnceprojects\PDFGeneration\thead.css http://cvldev.isni.co/Print.aspx?p=eyJBc3NldExpc3QiOiI3MiIsIlJlcG9ydENvZGUiOiJBQ0FOIiwiRGF0ZUZyb20iOiIxOC8xMS8yMDE1IDAwOjAwIiwiRGF0ZVRvIjoiMTgvMTEvMjAxNSAyMzo1OSIsIkxhc3RSZXBvcnRlZCI6IjI0IiwiU2hvd0FsbCI6ZmFsc2UsIlNwZWVkVHJlc2hvbGQiOjAsIlJlcG9ydFR5cGUiOiIiLCJGdWVsUHJpY2VQZXJMaXRlciI6MSwiQ2hhcnRUeXBlIjoiQ29sdW1uM0QifQ== E:\freelarnceprojects\PDFGeneration\PDFFiles\ba91230f-c6e8-4163-bf8c-b4228fe497f8.txt.pdf
```

Thanks in Advance for help .

Comment: I didn't get your point

Comment: Your question has the pdfbox label at the bottom, but does not seem to be related to pdfbox. Or is it related in a way that is not obvious?

Comment: Sorry it is not related to pdfbox, but any help i can regarding the border problem of SVG?

Comment: No help from me, sorry, I'm a PDFBox guy, not a css or SVG guy.